# In probability, what does P(A-B) stand for?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have the next problem:

Prove that $\forall A, B \subseteq \Omega, P(A-B) \ge P(A)-P(B)$

But, what does $P(A-B)$ mean? I thought it could mean the probability of all the events in $A$ that are not shared with $B$. Which is $P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $P(A-B) = P(A)$

If they are not mutually exclusive, then $P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B)$

If $A$ and $B$ completely overlap, that is $A=B$, then $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(B)$

If the previous statements are correct, then it implies that $P(A-B) \ge P(A)-P(B)$, because worst case scenario,$P(A-B) = P(A) - P(B)$, and best case scenario, $P(A-B) = P(A)$

Am I right?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: are you sure it's not $A / B$?

Comment: The problem is written as $A-B$.

Comment: Some authors take $A-B$ to be the same as $A \setminus B$, i.e. anything that is in $A$ but not in $B$.

Comment: You are right.  $A-B$ is an alternative notation for 'set difference', also often denoted $A\backslash B$.  So as you point out, $A-B=A-(A\cap B)$

Comment: So, for what I understand, that is the same as the definition I provided: $P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

Comment: In essence you are correct, but I would not use that as a definition. The definitions should be stated in terms of sets. The rules of probabilities (measures) make your statement true though.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument looks okay but is a little imprecise about cases in between the worst and best cases.  You should explicitly point out that $P(A \cap B) \le P(B)$.

Why not just use the monotonicity of $P$? Since $A \subset (A - B) \cup B$, you have $$P(A) \le P(A - B) + P(B).$$

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought about it. And you are right, it is imprecise.